# Python, etree: how to copy instance into new instance of a inherited class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, elementtree

I wrote a class which is inherited from xml.etree.ElementTree.Element class to extend that class with methods to show the complete tag name of the etree element and an easy way to replace the complete content of an element with a XML value from a string..

In the **init** method of the new class i just want to have a copy of an etree Element passed as parameter when instanciated.

First try was:

```
def __init__(self, elem):
     self = elem
```

But then the "subtags" list of the passed "Element" got lost.

The solution below works but is there a "smarter" way to copy the complete "elem" into the new object ?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#
# this class allows to replace the content including all subelement of an etree element
# by an XML string content
#

class xmltag(ET.Element):

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, elem):

        self.tag = elem.tag
        self.text = elem.text
        self.attrib = elem.attrib
        self.tail = elem.tail
        for s in next(elem.iter()):
            self.append(s)


    # get string of complete start tag name                    
    def __get_tag_start(self):
        tag="<"+self.tag
        for k in self.attrib.keys():
            tag=tag+" "+k+"=\"" + self.attrib[k] + "\""

        return tag+">"

    # get string of end tag name
    def __get_tag_end(self):
        return "</" + self.tag + ">" + (self.tail or "")

    # get string of whole content between start and end tag
    def get_tag_content(self):

        content=self.text or ""
        for s in next(self.iter()):
            xs=xmltag(s)               
            content=content+xs.__get_tag_start()
            content=content+(xs.text or "")
            content=content+xs.__get_tag_end()

        return content

    # change tag name
    def set_tag_name(self,tagname):
        self.tag=tagname    

    # change content
    def set_tag_content(self,content):
        try:
            elem=ET.fromstring(self.__get_tag_start()+content+self.__get_tag_end())

            self.clear()
            self.tag = elem.tag
            self.text = elem.text
            self.attrib = elem.attrib
            self.tail = elem.tail
            for s in next(elem.iter()):
                self.append(s)

            elem.clear()

        except:
            pass

#
# testdata
#

xmldata="""<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>"""

#
# MAIN
#

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
    element=root.find("country")

    if ET.iselement(element):

        x=xmltag(element)
        print(x.get_tag_content())

        x.set_tag_content("abc")
        print(ET.tostring(x,encoding="unicode"))

        x.set_tag_content("EFG")
        print(ET.tostring(x,encoding="unicode"))

        x.set_tag_name("test")
        print(ET.tostring(x,encoding="unicode"))
```

Comment: Doing `self = something` doesn't change anything. You are just binding the name `self` to something else for the duration of the execution of `__init__`, but outside the references doesn't change. Since you have a working solution and you want to improve it you should probably move this question to codereview SE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [classes in Python for a beginner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993089/classes-in-python-for-a-beginner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This corrects the error in your original `__init__()` method:

```
def __init__(self, elem):
    self.elem = elem
```

This copies the whole `elem` into your instance and you can now access its properties, such as `self.elem.tag` or `self.elem.text`.